# Strange behaviour of Java PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I have the following code

```
try{
    sql = "Select Time, Text WHERE Sender =?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, "ABC");
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
}catch(SQLException){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

And get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Sender ='ABC'' at line 1

There is an extra `'` in my SQL query, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 4):

It's not the "extra" `'` that's the issue. You actually need that for your DB to understand the text you're providing.

The issue is that you're issuing a SELECT statement that is requesting fields from a table which you have not specified. You need to add the table name:

```sql
Select Time, Text FROM <tablename here> WHERE Sender =?
```

**Edit:** Apparently MariaDB [doesn't consider `time` and `text` as reserved words](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/reserved-words/#exceptions) as @Andreas pointed out in a comment on this answer.

Comment: `TEXT` and `TIME` are not [reserved words in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/reserved-words/#exceptions): *Some keywords are exceptions for historical reasons, and are permitted as unquoted identifiers. These include: ..., `TEXT`, `TIME`, ...*.